# Getting Duration Time Units of a task in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

Is there a method in VBA I can call to obtain the time unit (Such as d,ed,hr,min,etc.) of a specific task? I'm currently making a macro that takes a delta between 2 duration fields. I get the correct number but would like to attach a time unit to it.

Comment: Ignore the downvote; it likely came from someone who knows nothing about MS Project. This is a perfectly reasonable MS Project VBA question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [GetField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/task-getfield-method-project) method to return the task field value as *displayed in the user interface*. For example:

```
Public Function GetUnits() As String

    Dim diplayValue As String
    diplayValue = ActiveProject.Tasks(1).GetField(pjTaskDuration)
    ' strip off numeric portion
    GetUnits = Mid$(diplayValue, Len(CStr(Val(diplayValue))) + 1)

End Function
```